# Sort pages in loop by admin's page attributes order field?

Tags: admin, loop, sort

Is it possible to sort pages in the loop using the admin's order field (under page attributes)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, use the `orderby` and `order` clause in your query posts.

```
query_posts( array('orderby'=>'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

See: [WP_Query#Order](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) for reference

Comment: Please note that you also need to use `order` argument, example: `'order'   => 'ASC'`.